# GetObject error in new version of SolidWorks

Tags: vba, solidworks

I have a user who in 2018 copied a macro from the web. After being upgraded to 2020 the macro can't get past the first line;

`Set swApp = GetObject(,"Application.SldWorks")`

The error is

> Run-time error '429' ActiveX component can't create object

I tried to reset the libraries and have gone through multiple forum posts looking a solution. [This post](http://help.solidworks.com/2018/english/api/sldworksapiprogguide/Overview/VBA_Macros_Type_Libraries_and_SolidWorks_Upgrade.htm) was the closest to my issue.

Below is the full code;

```vb
Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks

Public Sub main()

    Set swApp = GetObject(,"Application.SldWorks")

    Dim ActiveDoc As ModelDoc2
    Set ActiveDoc = GetObject(, "Sldworks.Application").ActiveDoc

    If Not ActiveDoc Is Nothing Then
        If ActiveDoc.GetType = 2 Then
            GoTo Traverse
        End If
    End If
    MsgBox ("This macro should be run, with an open assembly as the active document.")
    Exit Sub

Traverse:
            
    Dim myModel As ModelDoc2
    Set myModel = ActiveDoc
    Call Traverse(myModel, myModel.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration.Name)

    MsgBox ("Done")

End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you running this macro - what is the host application?

Comment: @TimWilliams Inside of Solidworks itself

Comment: Can't you just use `Application` as a reference to the host application? That's typically how it works in VBA. Not sure why you'd need `GetObject` here (but then again I've never used Solidworks...)

Comment: @TimWilliams I have 0 experience with it as well. I am almost entirely an excel guy, so this is new territory for me. Having said that I did try setting 'Set SwApp = application.sldworks' and received the same error

Comment: @TimWilliams which is part of the reason why I believed this to be a library references issue as alluded to in this post. It would seem to be more of an issue of allowing the argument to execute than it was about passing the wrong argument (hopefully i used the proper terminology there).

Comment: `Set swApp = Application.SldWorks` should work fine...  Maybe look at https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/32861 which seems like a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use reserved names like `ActiveDoc` as a variable name. You don't need to use `GetObject` on objects that are already directly referenced by the host. You don't need `Call` anymore.

I only get the error that you see if I use the `GetObject` command that you have there.

I have tested this code in SolidWorks 2020:

```
Option Explicit

Dim swApp As Object

Sub main()    
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Dim thisDoc As ModelDoc2
    Set thisDoc = swApp.ActiveDoc
    If Not thisDoc Is Nothing Then
        If thisDoc.GetType = 2 Then
            Dim myModel As ModelDoc2
            Set myModel = thisDoc
            Traverse myModel, myModel.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration.Name
            MsgBox "Done"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    MsgBox "This macro should be run, with an open assembly as the active document."
End Sub
```